# use particle from particle designer to a project

Tags: iphone, xcode, particles

I would like to use my particle created with particle designer in my xcode project that is not a cocos 2D project.Can I use it ? And if yes how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particle Designer was created by Michael Daley, author of [Learning iOS Game Programming](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321699424). Particle Designer was a tool that was developed over the course of the book to help implement Particle Effects. The details of particle usage in a regular project are in this book, which is about iOS game programming with regular OpenGL ES (no Cocos2D).

Michael also wrote several [tutorials, one of which is about Particle Emitters](http://www.71squared.com/2009/05/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-8-particle-emitter/). I'm not sure if it works with Particle Designer effects though.